# Facebook Page Crawler / Access tokens

Tags: facebook, api, authorization

I know pretty well that this topic has been discussed very intensively (I read a lot all over the day).

Still, how probable is it that FB might allow me to create a frontend crawler for a non-commercial, non-public research university project?

My crawler should repeatedly lookup a very limited number of specific public fan pages and collect anonymized data like number of fans, status updates and their number of likes and number of comments each.

What I would like to show is what kind of topics in media pages are "liked" and discussed most and how that develops over time. I know about FB's restricted TOS. Thanks for your opinion on that.

The second question concerns technological approach / authorization: Reading a fan page's number of fans, status updates and their number of likes each - could I even use the API/OpenGraph for such a crawler? I think for reading page walls, you need an access token at any cost, and realizing an automatic "crawler" via an application therefore is not possible I guess (as apps only react to users' actions and cannot act like cron jobs for example)?

As you see, I am pretty new to FB development and logic. Thanks so much for your expertise.

Answer (score 0):

If you mainly target public pages then you should be ok.

You need to have a facebook app and then you can [authenticate as the app](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/) from your program.
You will get an app token with which you should be able to use in order to crawl public pages data.

If you check the documentation for the [Page object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) you'll see in the tables (fields and connections) that most of what's in the *Permissions* column is either "No access token or user access_token" or "any valid access_token or user access_token", if you have the app token you're good.

Also, and I think this is something you'll be interested in, the Page object has the "talking_about_count" field.

So, yes you can do it, at least most of it.
As for the TOS, since all of this is perfectly ok and straight from their official documentation, there's no problem.